# What could be causing segmentation fault in the following code?

Tags: c++, image-processing, segmentation-fault

I've used 640, 480, 0 as an input, but it gives segmentation fault. WHat could be causing this to happen?

```
/* Changes the size of an image, allocating memory as necessary, and
 setting all pixels to fillcolor. Returns 0 on success, or a non-zero error code.*/
int Image::resize( unsigned int width,  unsigned int height, uint8_t fillcolor ){
    if(pixels) {
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            delete[] pixels[i];
        }
        delete[] pixels;
    }

    pixels = new uint8_t*[height];

    if(pixels == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)  {
        pixels[i] = new uint8_t[width];
        if(pixels[i] == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            pixels[i][j] = fillcolor;
        }
    }

    cols = width;
    rows = height;
    return 0;
}
```

I've used 640, 480, 0 as an input, but it gives segmentation fault. WHat could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to swap "width" and "height":

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        pixels[i][j] = fillcolor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what could be causing segmentation fault in this code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868397/segmentation-fault-when-loading-a-file

It seems to be a similar problem, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

```
pixels = new uint8_t*[height];
```

The first dimension of this two-dimensional array is `height`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        pixels[i][j] = fillcolor;
    }
}
```

This code uses `width` for the first dimension of the `pixels` array. The first dimension ranges from 0 to `width-1`, but it actually contains 0 to `height-1`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what could be causing segmentation fault in this code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868397/segmentation-fault-when-loading-a-file

It seems to be a similar problem